# Java Reflection/BeanUtils issue

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans

I'm trying to populate a bean with some table driven attribute:value pairs. I retrieve them from a MySQL table, and populate a hashmap just fine. I iterate through the hashmap, and if I use PropertyUtils.setProperty() I get a "Class does not have setter for *" error. If I use BeanUtils.setProperty() the bean never gets populated. Here's the sample:

```
public class DBDrivenPayloadHandler extends GDE{
DbDrivenPayloadHandlerBean bean;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void populateBean() throws Exception {
    ITransaction trans = new MySQLTransaction();
    IAdapterDataMapDAO adapterDataMap = new MySQLAdapterDataMapDAO();
    adapterDataMap.setTransaction(trans);

    HashMap<String, String> values = adapterDataMap.getHashMap(super.getCurrentAccountId()); 
    //hashmap gets populated correctly with correct variable names and values != "-1";

    DbDrivenPayloadHandlerBean bean = new DbDrivenPayloadHandlerBean(); 
    //We have a bean with all the intialized variable values

    Iterator it = values.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        try {
            PropertyUtils.setProperty(bean, (String) entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()); 
            //PropertyUtils will give a setter not found error. BeanUtils never sets the values. 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void getInfo(String fileName) {
    try {
        populateBean();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    APPTS_FULLNAME_POS = bean.getAPPTS_FULLNAME_POS();
    APPTS_DATETIME_POS = bean.getAPPTS_DATETIME_POS();
    //Both still -1;
    super.getInfo(filename);
}
```

And here's the Bean (or at least some of it):

```
public class DbDrivenPayloadHandlerBean {
int APPTS_FULLNAME_POS = -1;
int APPTS_DATETIME_POS = -1;


public DbDrivenPayloadHandlerBean() {
    super();
}

public int getAPPTS_FULLNAME_POS() {
    return APPTS_FULLNAME_POS;
}

public void setAPPTS_FULLNAME_POS(String APPTS_FULLNAME_POS) {
    this.APPTS_FULLNAME_POS = Integer.parseInt(APPTS_FULLNAME_POS);
}   

public int getAPPTS_DATETIME_POS() {
    return APPTS_DATETIME_POS;
}

public void setAPPTS_DATETIME_POS(String APPTS_DATETIME_POS) {
    this.APPTS_DATETIME_POS = Integer.parseInt(APPTS_DATETIME_POS);
}
```

Sorry guys, BeanUtils does the trick. I just don't want to be allowing setters that take Strings. I guess reflection does the casting for you. Apologies.

Comment: Post the full stack trace. Also, use Java naming conventions. That's what Beans depend on.

Comment: setter for an int field shoud be like `setXXX(int xxx)`

Comment: Your fields are of type `int`, and your setters take `String`. This is not how Beans work.

Comment: Not possible. The attribute values table will need to accomodate strings. Therefore, all booleans and ints will need to be parsed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution as stated above: don't try to cast for BeanUtils.

```
public class DBDrivenPayloadHandler extends GDE{
DbDrivenPayloadHandlerBean bean;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void populateBean() throws Exception {
    ITransaction trans = new MySQLTransaction();
    IAdapterDataMapDAO adapterDataMap = new MySQLAdapterDataMapDAO();
    adapterDataMap.setTransaction(trans);

    HashMap<String, String> values = adapterDataMap.getHashMap(super.getCurrentAccountId());        
    this.bean = new DbDrivenPayloadHandlerBean(); 

    Iterator it = values.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        try {
            BeanUtils.setProperty(bean, (String) entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void getInfo(String fileName) {
    try {
        populateBean();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    APPTS_FULLNAME_POS = bean.getAPPTS_FULLNAME_POS();
    APPTS_DATETIME_POS = bean.getAPPTS_DATETIME_POS();
    //Both still -1;
    super.getInfo(filename);
}
```

Bean

```
public class DbDrivenPayloadHandlerBean {
int APPTS_FULLNAME_POS = -1;
int APPTS_DATETIME_POS = -1;


public DbDrivenPayloadHandlerBean() {
    super();
}

public int getAPPTS_FULLNAME_POS() {
    return APPTS_FULLNAME_POS;
}

public void setAPPTS_FULLNAME_POS(int APPTS_FULLNAME_POS) {
    this.APPTS_FULLNAME_POS = APPTS_FULLNAME_POS;
}   

public int getAPPTS_DATETIME_POS() {
    return APPTS_DATETIME_POS;
}

public void setAPPTS_DATETIME_POS(String APPTS_DATETIME_POS) {
    this.APPTS_DATETIME_POS = APPTS_DATETIME_POS;
}
```